# What is the most accurate estimate of total possible number of chess games

Tags: chessboard

What is the most accurate estimate for the total possible number of chess games. I already know about Shannon's number, I'm just wondering if there's anything higher than that.

Answer (score -1):

On the Wikipedia page for [Shannon's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_number) it states

> Allis also estimated the game-tree complexity to be at least $10^{123}$, "based on an average branching factor of $35$ and an average game length of $80$"